# Correlated Subquery can't access column from outer query

Tags: mysql

Given the following query which contains a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sc.caseID) AS 'TotalCases',  

(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT se1.caseID)        
 FROM scEvent AS se1          
 INNER JOIN scCase AS sc1 
         ON (se1.caseID = sc1.caseID AND 
             sc1.vendorID = '258' )   <-- this is what I want to make dynamic

  WHERE sc1.vendorID = sc.vendorID
  AND ( se1.escalationLevel = 1 OR
        sc.escalationLevel = 1) ) AS 'level1Count'


FROM scCase AS sc 

WHERE sc.vendorID = '258'
```

If I try to change the inner join on the subquery to be dynamic like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sc.caseID) AS 'TotalCases', 

(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT se1.caseID)        
 FROM scEvent AS se1          
 INNER JOIN scCase AS sc1 
         ON (se1.caseID = sc1.caseID AND 
             sc1.vendorID = sc.vendorID ) <-- only thing that's different

  WHERE sc1.vendorID = sc.vendorID
  AND ( se1.escalationLevel = 1 OR
        sc.escalationLevel = 1) ) AS 'level1Count'


FROM scCase AS sc 

WHERE sc.vendorID = '258'
```

Then I get the error: *Unknown column 'sc.vendorID' in 'on clause'*

How can I make the vendor ID in the correlated subquery dynamic depending on the outer record. Is it even possible?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you move the condition to the `WHERE` clause?: `AND 
             sc1.vendorID = sc.vendorID` Oh wait, you already have it there! Why does it need to go in the `ON` too?

Comment: Your comment got me thinking. I don't even need the vendor ID in the join.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what exactly the query is trying to count but you can most liekly rewrite much more simply.

- One idea would be to get rid of the subquery in the `SELECT` and put the join in the main `FROM` clause.
- Another would be to remove the table that is duplicated from the internal `FROM`.

Script for 2nd idea:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT sc.caseID) AS TotalCases, 

  ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT se1.caseID)        
    FROM scEvent AS se1          
    WHERE se1.caseID = sc.caseID
      AND ( se1.escalationLevel = 1
         OR sc.escalationLevel = 1
          )
  ) AS level1Count

FROM scCase AS sc 

WHERE sc.vendorID = '258' ;
```